# Setting the user for extended form

Tags: python, django

I have made my own custom user model and have made a form which then extends that with some extra fields (I am doing this as I will have two registration forms). The second form has a onetoonefield with the user model however I figure out how to tell the onetoonefield which user it should be set to. Could anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks

Models -

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('staff status', default=False,
        help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.')
    is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=True,
        help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
#https://www.lasolution.be/blog/creating-custom-user-model-django-16-part-1.html

class StudentModel(models.Model):
    email = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    area_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=area_code_choice, blank=True)
    referral = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=referral_choices)
```

Forms -

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=("Password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Both Passwords must match!")
        return password2

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = StudentModel
        fields = ['birth_date', 'area_code', 'contact_number', 'referral']
```

View -

```
def register_student(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_user = UserForm(request.POST)
        form_student = StudentForm(request.POST)

        if form_user.is_valid() and form_student.is_valid():

            form_student.email = form_user.email
            profile = form_student.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()
            return redirect('listing', profile.pk)
    else:
        form_user = UserForm()
        form_student = StudentForm()

    context_dict = {
        'form_user': form_user,
        'form_student': form_student,
    }

    return render(request, 'register_student.html', context_dict)
```

Currently I am trying to set it via this `form_student.email = form_user.email`however this returns the following error

Error -

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/register-student/

Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'main',
 'listings',
 'profiles',
 'opus_login')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Other folders\Desktop\Student Job Search\code\opus_jobs_project\opus_login\views.py" in register_student
  13.             form_student.email = form_user.email

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/register-student/
Exception Value: 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'email'
```

Comment: You need to share your view code, but it looks like you need to do `form_user.cleaned_data["email"]`

Comment: Hi Karthikr, the view code is there. But there would I put what you suggested?

Comment: Yes, please check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the example i placed here :

```
def user_registration(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        form1 = StudentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():

            cd = form.cleaned_data
            cd1 = form1.cleaned_data

            user = form.save()

            user.username = user.email  # if u want username as email u can do like this (optional)

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = form1.save(commit=False)

            profile.user = user

            # Now we save the StudentForm model instance.

            profile.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user-login/')
        else:
            error = form.errors
            error1 = form1.errors
            return render(request, 'registration.html', locals())
    else:
        form = UserForm
        form1 = StudentForm
    return render(request, 'registration.html', locals())
```